# Is there a way to position my Article title in Drupal 8 teaser?

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I have In teasers  and other custom display types I would like the image to appear above the title.  However, when I try to manage the display fields from the admin menu there is no way to change the  title or byline.

In other words  the only field I choose to display from that menu is image, but on the page the title, date and author appear.

```
 <title>
 Submitted by <author> on <date>
```

Is there a way outside CSS to move these things around

Comment: Since they are not present as extra fields you have to edit the node template. Use theme suggestion and chose the display you want to alter, ie. teaser.

Comment: What do you meant theme suggestion?  Is that a module or a configuration page?

The only template I can find is node template is it possible to create a template just for teasers or whatever other display modes I create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to do it in node templates or you can try out [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds), but I'm not sure about the exact state of it in Drupal 8.

Update: Didn't see that you also mean the byline. That one is easy, that's a setting on the node type form whether it should be shown or not.